# spring integration kafka listener thread reads multiple partitions when concurrency = partition count

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-integration, spring-kafka

I set up a Spring Integration flow to process a topic having 3 partitions and set the listener container's concurrency to 3.  As expected, I see three threads processing batches from all 3 partitions.  However, I see that in some cases, one of the listener threads may process a single batch containing messages from multiple partitions.  My data is partitioned in kafka by an id so that it may be processed concurrently with other ids, but not with the same ids on another thread (which is what I was surprised to observe is happening). I thought from reading the docs that each thread would be assigned a partition.  I'm using a KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter like this:

```
private static final Class<List<MyEvent>> payloadClass = (Class<List<MyEvent>>)(Class) List.class;

public KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec<String, MyEvent> myChannelAdapterSpec() {
        return Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(tstatEventConsumerFactory(),
                KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode.batch, "my-topic") //3 partitions
                .configureListenerContainer(c -> {
                    c.ackMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.BATCH);
                    c.id(_ID);
                    c.concurrency(3);
                    RecoveringBatchErrorHandler errorHandler = new RecoveringBatchErrorHandler(
                            (record, exception) -> log.error("failed to handle record at offset {}: {}",
                                    record.offset(), record.value(), exception),
                            new FixedBackOff(FixedBackOff.DEFAULT_INTERVAL, 2)
                    );
                    c.errorHandler(errorHandler);
                });
    }
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow myIntegrationFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(myChannelAdapterSpec())
                .handle(payloadClass, (payload, headers) -> {
                    service.performSink(payload);
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }
```

How do I set this up so that each listener container thread only processes messages from one partition?

Comment: Are listeners running into rebalancing state due to slow processing?

Comment: @Gibbs Yes, in fact I confirmed that this is happening.  The logs show we had a rebalance immediately prior to a single thread processing messages from 2 different partitions.

Comment: The logs (part of rebalance, I believe) also suggest that a single consumer is assigned all three partitions: `2022-05-22 04:44:51.051  INFO 10 --- [ryAdapter-1-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-xxx-4, groupId=xxx] Finished assignment for group at generation 415: {xxx-4-9808b498-2a1a-4cd4-b103-995df3ab03af=Assignment(partitions=[myTopic-0, myTopic-1, myTopic-2])}`

Comment: Consider to increase `max.poll.interval.ms` to avoid rebalance: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_max.poll.interval.ms. The `concurrency = 3` means not only 3 threads, but also 3 independent `KafkaConsumer` instances in the same group. So, as long as one of them cannot keep up with the  `max.poll.interval.ms`, the rebalance starts.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Thanks for the suggestion.  I can increase `max.poll.interval.ms`.   I assume that unless a rebalance occurs, each container thread will use a single kafka consumer that will read from a single partition (assuming concurrency = partition count).  But is there additionally a way that I can keep from ever getting a batch with messages from multiple partitions, even if a rebalance does occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is there additionally a way that I can keep from ever getting a batch with messages from multiple partitions, even if a rebalance does occur?

That's not how consumer group works. If you would like to have a "sticky" consumers, then consider to use a manual assignment. See the channel adapter factory based on the `TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions`:

```
/**
 * Create an initial
 * {@link KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec}.
 * @param consumerFactory the {@link ConsumerFactory}.
 * @param listenerMode the {@link KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode}.
 * @param topicPartitions the {@link TopicPartitionOffset} vararg.
 * @param <K> the Kafka message key type.
 * @param <V> the Kafka message value type.
 * @return the KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec.
 */
public static <K, V>
KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec<K, V> messageDrivenChannelAdapter(
        ConsumerFactory<K, V> consumerFactory,
        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.ListenerMode listenerMode,
        TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions) {
```

Then it is not going to be treated as consumer group and you have to create several channel adapters pointing each to its specific partition. All of this channel adapters may emit messages to the same `MessageChannel`.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I will give this a try.  To confirm, is it true that with my current approach, each listener container thread will get a single kafka consumer that will read from just one partition -- until/unless a rebalance occurs?  In other words, I almost get what I want, just not a guarantee that my listener will always get batches from a single partition?

Comment: That's correct. As far as there are less consumers than partitions one they are going to be distributed between them and their poll action is going to happen against those subscribed partitions. I'm not though what is the concern about several partition on one batch since you send everything into the same `handle()`. You may consider to split your batch from Kafka to artificial batches by partition before calling your `handle()`.

Comment: My `handle()` upserts data in a Postgres database.  Data is partitioned in kafka by (part of) the primary key on the table getting the upsert.  Bad things may happen if concurrent transactions attempt to upsert data for the same key, which is what I wish to avoid by the guarantee that each call to `handle()` gets a set of keys that has no intersection with the set of keys passed to a concurrent call to `handle()`.

Comment: Right. So, then better to go with manual assignment: you just won't suffer any rebalance features and every single thread is going to deal only with its own partition. You always can use a `channel()` in Java DSL to route from different inbound channel adapter into the same process. Also you still may consider to use a `split()` to form sub-batches grouped by the key you mention. So, you `handle()` will always upsert only a batch specific to the partition.

Comment: Okay, so it appears I can do manual assignment using the constructor with `TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions` instead of `String... topics`.  So in my example, I can pass an array with `{new TopicPartitionOffset("my-topic", 0), new TopicPartitionOffset("my-topic",1), new TopicPartitionOffset("my-topic",2)}` and I leave concurrency at 3.  This seems to work... but I wasn't sure what you meant by _you have to create several channel adapters pointing each to its specific partition_.

Comment: Oh! You are right. Yes, I missed that fact that we still support concurrency even if manual assignment. So, those your provided partitions are distributed by the container according the concurrency value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245058/discussion-between-chad-showalter-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: I don't do "chats" over here. I have other tasks to do in parallel. I'm fully OK to continue discussion via comment, but only when my busy-spin got a slot to look into this again.

Comment: Very good. So just to be sure I understand, using the combination of the `TopicPartitionOffset... topicPartitions` constructor and setting concurrency=3 in my example will result in the behavior I want: each invocation of handle() is guaranteed to receive a batch of messages containing only messages from a single partition?

Comment: That's correct. There is another way - "over consume". Have a concurrency higher than partitions number. So, those idle consumers will take abandoned partitions when rebalance happens.